# From current style CSS3 Animation

Tags: css

I have a problem and the answer I found are not precise enough.

I have 2 DIV. A div at left:-100%; and a div at left:100%;

I would like in ONE animation, animate those div to smoothly go from their actual Left, to left:0%;

i tried adding just

```
.animSlide{
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: anim;
}
@keyframes anim {
    to {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

But this brake all steps on animation. I mean, after 0.5s my div go from actual left to 0%;

So, is there a way to say

```
@keyframes anim {
    from{
         left:current%;
    }
    to {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

Thx for help

**EDIT : The ABOVE code should work. So my problem come from another part of the code...
This is what i do basically : https://jsfiddle.net/Crocsx/rwyt400n/**

Comment: "I mean, after 0.5s my div go from actual left to 0%" Isn't that what you want? That's precisely what the CSS you have does, and is the intended method. How does the behavior you observe not meet your expectations?

Comment: i want it to slide from current pos to 0% over time.
so at 0s it's at current post at 0.25sec at 50% of the distance etc.... 

Here it just go from current pos to 0% after 0.5 without any smooth transition

Comment: By default, if you don't set a `from` state in your animation, it should start at the current position of the element. So if I understand correctly what you want is the default behavior, so there must be a problem somewhere else. Is that the behavior you want : https://jsfiddle.net/wsj920ck/ (red one coming from outside, left). EDIT : @Crocsx I didn't see your comment, is there the same problem in my example ?

Comment: Your fiddle and the fiddle of the guy below work perfectly i think there is an error in what i do. I will edit the question i think

Comment: @Crocsx As far as I can tell, the problem isn't in the code you put in your comment because I copied it, only added some rules, and it works.

Comment: Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/Crocsx/rwyt400n/

I'm maybe tired, but i can't find my error :3

Comment: @Crocsx Ah, in reality it's more complicated. I will write an answer because my hypothesis and solution won't enter in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Crocsx/rwyt400n/) provided in comment by the author.

This is not a very good answer because I only have an hypothesis about the problem, however I have a solution.
The problem, I think, is that the value of `left` after the animation is "virtual". When you start the second animation (by putting the class "slide_to_right") it look at the real value which is still `100%`, even though you see it as `0%`, and start the animation from this point (that's why it is not animated from 0%).

Because you are using JS to change the state of the elements, instead of using animations, you can use [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions). It will allow your element to be animated automatically when changing between the 2 states and it is easier to set in this case (less code).
Thanks to this property, all you have to do is set the transition property on your sliding element. And then change its state in JS. In this case you want to alternate between `left:100%` and `left:0%`. So the transition property is written like this : `transition: left 5s;`.

To set the different left values, you can directly change the style in JS. Or have a class prepared in your css and add this class to your element. In this case, 2 classes `.left` and `.right` work great.
The transition will take care of the animation.

Here is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/rwyt400n/4/ (I changed the id to classes).

Comment: Thx for the moment i will take the working solution ^^

Will keep you updated if i find why it doesn't work or a way to fix my fiddle ^^ 

thx again for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@-moz-keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

you can specify a css property value that you want the animation to begin with, and end with. you can also split this `keyframe` into more than just `0%` and `100%`.

For ex.

```
@keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateY(-75px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateY(-25px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wqzyv76/).

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    animation: anim 5s;
}
.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    animation: anim 5s;
}
@keyframes anim {
    to {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. and my code is like that. I think there is a different problem in what i do :3